# How to iterate over popen output?

Tags: ruby

I have this simple ruby script:

```
redcricket@dev-006:~$ cat simple.rb  
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby

IO.popen 'ls -l', 'r+' do |f|
        puts f.gets
end
```

and when I run it the only output I get is this ...

```
redcricket@dev-006:~$ ./simple.rb  
total 32
```

... what I expected was this ...

```
redcricket@smp-mig-dev-006:~$ ls -l
total 32
drwxr-xr-x  4 redcricket co 4096 Dec  5 12:23 applications
-rw-r--r--  1 redcricket co  464 Oct  5 16:23 config
drwxr-xr-x 72 redcricket co 4096 Dec  5 15:11 docs
drwxr-xr-x  3 root    root  4096 Dec  5 12:14 oradiag_root
drwxr-xr-x  5 redcricket co 4096 Dec  5 16:22 platform
-rwxr-xr-x  1 redcricket co  373 Dec  5 16:30 process_yum_output.rb
-rwxr-xr-x  1 redcricket co 2159 Nov 28 16:24 SetupSSHPK.sh
-rwxr-xr-x  1 redcricket co  142 Dec  5 16:31 simple.rb
```

... I guess I need to iterate over f.gets somehow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Ruby [`IO#gets` method](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-gets) just returns the next line of input from the IO object.

In order to get all of the lines you could call "gets" repeatedly until it's nil, or call [`read`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-read) to get the entire string, or [`readlines`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-readlines) to get the lines of input in an array.

```ruby
IO.popen('ls -l','r') { |f| puts $_ while f.gets }
IO.popen('ls -l','r') { |f| puts f.read }
IO.popen('ls -l','r') { |f| puts f.readlines }
```

Answer (score 4):

The block passed to [`IO#popen`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-popen) is executed *once only*. It's not a loop. Think of the object which is passed to the block as a [`File`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/File.html)¹. If the second argument to `IO#popen` was `"r"` you can read that `File`; if it was `"w"` you can write to it.  After the control flow leaves the block the child process should be dead and the [`IO`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html) object you used to access it is neither valid nor available any longer.

If you want to get an array of lines call [`readlines`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-readlines) on the block's argument. If you want to iterate over them, call [`each`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-each), i.e.

```
IO.popen("ls", "r") { |io| io.each { |line| puts line } }
```

---

¹ To be precise, it's an instance of [`IO`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html).

Comment: This works fine (probably even better) without the `readlines`.

Answer (score 2):

I like:

```
IO.popen 'ls -l', 'r+' do |f|
  puts f.gets until f.eof?
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The block passed to `IO.popen` is only called once, being passed an IO object representing the pipe that was created.

Since you only call `gets` once on that object you will only receive a single line of the output from that command.  To get more lines you need to iterate over the IO object:

```
IO.popen %w{ls -l}, 'r' do |pipe|
  pipe.each do |line|
    puts "|#{line}"
  end
end
```